# HTML DOM form select option dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript code with country list.

```
var country_list = [
  {"country_code": "AD", "country_name": "Andorra"},
  {"country_code": "AE", "country_name": "United Arab Emirates"},
  {"country_code": "AF", "country_name": "Afghanistan"},
  {"country_code": "AG", "country_name": "Antigua and Barbuda"},
  {"country_code": "AI", "country_name": "Anguilla"},
  {"country_code": "AL", "country_name": "Albania"},
  {"country_code": "AM", "country_name": "Armenia"},
  {"country_code": "AN", "country_name": "Netherlands Antilles"},
  {"country_code": "AO", "country_name": "Angola"},
  {"country_code": "AQ", "country_name": "Antarctica"},
  {"country_code": "AR", "country_name": "Argentina"},
  {"country_code": "AS", "country_name": "American Samoa"},
  {"country_code": "AT", "country_name": "Austria"},
  {"country_code": "AU", "country_name": "Australia"},
  {"country_code": "AW", "country_name": "Aruba"},
  {"country_code": "AZ", "country_name": "Azerbaijan"},
  {"country_code": "BA", "country_name": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"},
  {"country_code": "BB", "country_name": "Barbados"},
  {"country_code": "BD", "country_name": "Bangladesh"},
  {"country_code": "BE", "country_name": "Belgium"},
  {"country_code": "BF", "country_name": "Burkina Faso"},
  {"country_code": "BG", "country_name": "Bulgaria"},
  {"country_code": "BH", "country_name": "Bahrain"},
  {"country_code": "BI", "country_name": "Burundi"},
  {"country_code": "BJ", "country_name": "Benin"},
  {"country_code": "BM", "country_name": "Bermuda"},
  {"country_code": "BN", "country_name": "Brunei Darussalam"},
  {"country_code": "BO", "country_name": "Bolivia"},
  {"country_code": "BR", "country_name": "Brazil"},
  {"country_code": "BS", "country_name": "Bahamas"},
  {"country_code": "BT", "country_name": "Bhutan"},
  {"country_code": "BV", "country_name": "Bouvet Island"},
  {"country_code": "BW", "country_name": "Botswana"},
  {"country_code": "BY", "country_name": "Belarus"},
  {"country_code": "BZ", "country_name": "Belize"},
  {"country_code": "CA", "country_name": "Canada"},
  {"country_code": "CC", "country_name": "Cocos (Keeling) Islands"},
  {"country_code": "CF", "country_name": "Central African Republic"},
  {"country_code": "CG", "country_name": "Congo"},
  {"country_code": "CH", "country_name": "Switzerland"},
  {"country_code": "CI", "country_name": "Cote D'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)"},
  {"country_code": "CK", "country_name": "Cook Islands"},
  {"country_code": "CL", "country_name": "Chile"},
  {"country_code": "CM", "country_name": "Cameroon"},
  {"country_code": "CN", "country_name": "China"},
  {"country_code": "CO", "country_name": "Colombia"},
  {"country_code": "CR", "country_name": "Costa Rica"},
  {"country_code": "CS", "country_name": "Czechoslovakia (former)"},
  {"country_code": "CU", "country_name": "Cuba"},
  {"country_code": "CV", "country_name": "Cape Verde"},
  {"country_code": "CX", "country_name": "Christmas Island"},
  {"country_code": "CY", "country_name": "Cyprus"},
  {"country_code": "CZ", "country_name": "Czech Republic"},
  {"country_code": "DE", "country_name": "Germany"},
  {"country_code": "DJ", "country_name": "Djibouti"},
  {"country_code": "DK", "country_name": "Denmark"},
  {"country_code": "DM", "country_name": "Dominica"},
  {"country_code": "DO", "country_name": "Dominican Republic"},
  {"country_code": "DZ", "country_name": "Algeria"},
  {"country_code": "EC", "country_name": "Ecuador"},
  {"country_code": "EE", "country_name": "Estonia"},
  {"country_code": "EG", "country_name": "Egypt"},
  {"country_code": "EH", "country_name": "Western Sahara"},
  {"country_code": "ER", "country_name": "Eritrea"},
  {"country_code": "ES", "country_name": "Spain"},
  {"country_code": "ET", "country_name": "Ethiopia"},
  {"country_code": "FI", "country_name": "Finland"},
  {"country_code": "FJ", "country_name": "Fiji"},
  {"country_code": "FK", "country_name": "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)"},
  {"country_code": "FM", "country_name": "Micronesia"},
  {"country_code": "FO", "country_name": "Faroe Islands"},
  {"country_code": "FR", "country_name": "France"},
  {"country_code": "FX", "country_name": "France, Metropolitan"},
  {"country_code": "GA", "country_name": "Gabon"},
  {"country_code": "GB", "country_name": "Great Britain (UK)"},
  {"country_code": "GD", "country_name": "Grenada"},
  {"country_code": "GE", "country_name": "Georgia"},
  {"country_code": "GF", "country_name": "French Guiana"},
  {"country_code": "GH", "country_name": "Ghana"},
  {"country_code": "GI", "country_name": "Gibraltar"},
  {"country_code": "GL", "country_name": "Greenland"},
  {"country_code": "GM", "country_name": "Gambia"},
  {"country_code": "GN", "country_name": "Guinea"},
  {"country_code": "GP", "country_name": "Guadeloupe"},
  {"country_code": "GQ", "country_name": "Equatorial Guinea"},
  {"country_code": "GR", "country_name": "Greece"},
  {"country_code": "GS", "country_name": "S. Georgia and S. Sandwich Isls."},
  {"country_code": "GT", "country_name": "Guatemala"},
  {"country_code": "GU", "country_name": "Guam"},
  {"country_code": "GW", "country_name": "Guinea-Bissau"},
  {"country_code": "GY", "country_name": "Guyana"},
  {"country_code": "HK", "country_name": "Hong Kong"},
  {"country_code": "HM", "country_name": "Heard and McDonald Islands"},
  {"country_code": "HN", "country_name": "Honduras"},
  {"country_code": "HR", "country_name": "Croatia (Hrvatska)"},
  {"country_code": "HT", "country_name": "Haiti"},
  {"country_code": "HU", "country_name": "Hungary"},
  {"country_code": "ID", "country_name": "Indonesia"},
  {"country_code": "IE", "country_name": "Ireland"},
  {"country_code": "IL", "country_name": "Israel"},
  {"country_code": "IN", "country_name": "India"},
  {"country_code": "IO", "country_name": "British Indian Ocean Territory"},
  {"country_code": "IQ", "country_name": "Iraq"},
  {"country_code": "IR", "country_name": "Iran"},
  {"country_code": "IS", "country_name": "Iceland"},
  {"country_code": "IT", "country_name": "Italy"},
  {"country_code": "JM", "country_name": "Jamaica"},
  {"country_code": "JO", "country_name": "Jordan"},
  {"country_code": "JP", "country_name": "Japan"},
  {"country_code": "KE", "country_name": "Kenya"},
  {"country_code": "KG", "country_name": "Kyrgyzstan"},
  {"country_code": "KH", "country_name": "Cambodia"},
  {"country_code": "KI", "country_name": "Kiribati"},
  {"country_code": "KM", "country_name": "Comoros"},
  {"country_code": "KN", "country_name": "Saint Kitts and Nevis"},
  {"country_code": "KP", "country_name": "Korea (North)"},
  {"country_code": "KR", "country_name": "Korea (South)"},
  {"country_code": "KW", "country_name": "Kuwait"},
  {"country_code": "KY", "country_name": "Cayman Islands"},
  {"country_code": "KZ", "country_name": "Kazakhstan"},
  {"country_code": "LA", "country_name": "Laos"},
  {"country_code": "LB", "country_name": "Lebanon"},
  {"country_code": "LC", "country_name": "Saint Lucia"},
  {"country_code": "LI", "country_name": "Liechtenstein"},
  {"country_code": "LK", "country_name": "Sri Lanka"},
  {"country_code": "LR", "country_name": "Liberia"},
  {"country_code": "LS", "country_name": "Lesotho"},
  {"country_code": "LT", "country_name": "Lithuania"},
  {"country_code": "LU", "country_name": "Luxembourg"},
  {"country_code": "LV", "country_name": "Latvia"},
  {"country_code": "LY", "country_name": "Libya"},
  {"country_code": "MA", "country_name": "Morocco"},
  {"country_code": "MC", "country_name": "Monaco"},
  {"country_code": "MD", "country_name": "Moldova"},
  {"country_code": "MG", "country_name": "Madagascar"},
  {"country_code": "MH", "country_name": "Marshall Islands"},
  {"country_code": "MK", "country_name": "Macedonia"},
  {"country_code": "ML", "country_name": "Mali"},
  {"country_code": "MM", "country_name": "Myanmar"},
  {"country_code": "MN", "country_name": "Mongolia"},
  {"country_code": "MO", "country_name": "Macau"},
  {"country_code": "MP", "country_name": "Northern Mariana Islands"},
  {"country_code": "MQ", "country_name": "Martinique"},
  {"country_code": "MR", "country_name": "Mauritania"},
  {"country_code": "MS", "country_name": "Montserrat"},
  {"country_code": "MT", "country_name": "Malta"},
  {"country_code": "MU", "country_name": "Mauritius"},
  {"country_code": "MV", "country_name": "Maldives"},
  {"country_code": "MW", "country_name": "Malawi"},
  {"country_code": "MX", "country_name": "Mexico"},
  {"country_code": "MY", "country_name": "Malaysia"},
  {"country_code": "MZ", "country_name": "Mozambique"},
  {"country_code": "NA", "country_name": "Namibia"},
  {"country_code": "NC", "country_name": "New Caledonia"},
  {"country_code": "NE", "country_name": "Niger"},
  {"country_code": "NF", "country_name": "Norfolk Island"},
  {"country_code": "NG", "country_name": "Nigeria"},
  {"country_code": "NI", "country_name": "Nicaragua"},
  {"country_code": "NL", "country_name": "Netherlands"},
  {"country_code": "NO", "country_name": "Norway"},
  {"country_code": "NP", "country_name": "Nepal"},
  {"country_code": "NR", "country_name": "Nauru"},
  {"country_code": "NT", "country_name": "Neutral Zone"},
  {"country_code": "NU", "country_name": "Niue"},
  {"country_code": "NZ", "country_name": "New Zealand (Aotearoa)"},
  {"country_code": "OM", "country_name": "Oman"},
  {"country_code": "PA", "country_name": "Panama"},
  {"country_code": "PE", "country_name": "Peru"},
  {"country_code": "PF", "country_name": "French Polynesia"},
  {"country_code": "PG", "country_name": "Papua New Guinea"},
  {"country_code": "PH", "country_name": "Philippines"},
  {"country_code": "PK", "country_name": "Pakistan"},
  {"country_code": "PL", "country_name": "Poland"},
  {"country_code": "PM", "country_name": "St. Pierre and Miquelon"},
  {"country_code": "PN", "country_name": "Pitcairn"},
  {"country_code": "PR", "country_name": "Puerto Rico"},
  {"country_code": "PT", "country_name": "Portugal"},
  {"country_code": "PW", "country_name": "Palau"},
  {"country_code": "PY", "country_name": "Paraguay"},
  {"country_code": "QA", "country_name": "Qatar"},
  {"country_code": "RE", "country_name": "Reunion"},
  {"country_code": "RO", "country_name": "Romania"},
  {"country_code": "RU", "country_name": "Russia"},
  {"country_code": "RW", "country_name": "Rwanda"},
  {"country_code": "SA", "country_name": "Saudi Arabia"},
  {"country_code": "Sb", "country_name": "Solomon Islands"},
  {"country_code": "SC", "country_name": "Seychelles"},
  {"country_code": "SD", "country_name": "Sudan"},
  {"country_code": "SE", "country_name": "Sweden"},
  {"country_code": "SG", "country_name": "Singapore"},
  {"country_code": "SH", "country_name": "St. Helena"},
  {"country_code": "SI", "country_name": "Slovenia"},
  {"country_code": "SJ", "country_name": "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands"},
  {"country_code": "SK", "country_name": "Slovak Republic"},
  {"country_code": "SL", "country_name": "Sierra Leone"},
  {"country_code": "SM", "country_name": "San Marino"},
  {"country_code": "SN", "country_name": "Senegal"},
  {"country_code": "SO", "country_name": "Somalia"},
  {"country_code": "SR", "country_name": "Suriname"},
  {"country_code": "ST", "country_name": "Sao Tome and Principe"},
  {"country_code": "SU", "country_name": "USSR (former)"},
  {"country_code": "SV", "country_name": "El Salvador"},
  {"country_code": "SY", "country_name": "Syria"},
  {"country_code": "SZ", "country_name": "Swaziland"},
  {"country_code": "TC", "country_name": "Turks and Caicos Islands"},
  {"country_code": "TD", "country_name": "Chad"},
  {"country_code": "TF", "country_name": "French Southern Territories"},
  {"country_code": "TG", "country_name": "Togo"},
  {"country_code": "TH", "country_name": "Thailand"},
  {"country_code": "TJ", "country_name": "Tajikistan"},
  {"country_code": "TK", "country_name": "Tokelau"},
  {"country_code": "TM", "country_name": "Turkmenistan"},
  {"country_code": "TN", "country_name": "Tunisia"},
  {"country_code": "TO", "country_name": "Tonga"},
  {"country_code": "TP", "country_name": "East Timor"},
  {"country_code": "TR", "country_name": "Turkey"},
  {"country_code": "TT", "country_name": "Trinidad and Tobago"},
  {"country_code": "TV", "country_name": "Tuvalu"},
  {"country_code": "TW", "country_name": "Taiwan"},
  {"country_code": "TZ", "country_name": "Tanzania"},
  {"country_code": "UA", "country_name": "Ukraine"},
  {"country_code": "UG", "country_name": "Uganda"},
  {"country_code": "UK", "country_name": "United Kingdom"},
  {"country_code": "UM", "country_name": "US Minor Outlying Islands"},
  {"country_code": "US", "country_name": "United States"},
  {"country_code": "UY", "country_name": "Uruguay"},
  {"country_code": "UZ", "country_name": "Uzbekistan"},
  {"country_code": "VA", "country_name": "Vatican City State (Holy See)"},
  {"country_code": "VC", "country_name": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"},
  {"country_code": "VE", "country_name": "Venezuela"},
  {"country_code": "VG", "country_name": "Virgin Islands (British)"},
  {"country_code": "VI", "country_name": "Virgin Islands (U.S.)"},
  {"country_code": "VN", "country_name": "Viet Nam"},
  {"country_code": "VU", "country_name": "Vanuatu"},
  {"country_code": "WF", "country_name": "Wallis and Futuna Islands"},
  {"country_code": "WS", "country_name": "Samoa"},
  {"country_code": "YE", "country_name": "Yemen"},
  {"country_code": "YT", "country_name": "Mayotte"},
  {"country_code": "YU", "country_name": "Yugoslavia"},
  {"country_code": "ZA", "country_name": "South Africa"},
  {"country_code": "ZM", "country_name": "Zambia"},
  {"country_code": "ZR", "country_name": "Zaire"},
  {"country_code": "ZW", "country_name": "Zimbabwe"}
];
```

Im trying to make a country field with select and option dropdown, where name of the countries will be full names and value sent to server will be the 2 letter abbreviation. the country United States also needs to be selected by default.

this is what i tried which isn't working

```
var select = document.getElementById("country");
        var options = country_list;
        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var opt = options[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            select.appendChild(el);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of problems there:

1. You've used `opt`, which is an object, for both the name and the value.
2. Rather than using `textContent`, the simplest way to add options to a select box is the `Option` constructor
3. There's no need at all to use a new variable, `options`, to refer to the array you already have an existing variable, `country_list`, referring to.

So:

```
var selectOptions = document.getElementById("country").options;
for(var i = 0; i < country_list.length; i++) {
    var opt = country_list[i];
    selectOptions.add(new Option(
        opt.country_name,
        opt.country_code
    ));
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var country_list = [{
  "country_code": "AD",
  "country_name": "Andorra"
}, {
  "country_code": "AE",
  "country_name": "United Arab Emirates"
}, {
  "country_code": "AF",
  "country_name": "Afghanistan"
}, {
  "country_code": "AG",
  "country_name": "Antigua and Barbuda"
}, {
  "country_code": "AI",
  "country_name": "Anguilla"
}, {
  "country_code": "AL",
  "country_name": "Albania"
}, {
  "country_code": "AM",
  "country_name": "Armenia"
}, {
  "country_code": "AN",
  "country_name": "Netherlands Antilles"
}, {
  "country_code": "AO",
  "country_name": "Angola"
}, {
  "country_code": "AQ",
  "country_name": "Antarctica"
}, {
  "country_code": "AR",
  "country_name": "Argentina"
}, {
  "country_code": "AS",
  "country_name": "American Samoa"
}, {
  "country_code": "AT",
  "country_name": "Austria"
}/*...and so on...*/];
var selectOptions = document.getElementById("country").options;
for (var i = 0; i < country_list.length; i++) {
  var opt = country_list[i];
  selectOptions.add(new Option(
    opt.country_name,
    opt.country_code
  ));
}
```

```html
<select id="country"></select>
```

Or (if you're working in an ES5 environment or applying a shim for `Array#forEach`):

```
var selectOptions = document.getElementById("country").options;
country_list.forEach(function(e) {
    selectOptions.add(new Option(
        e.country_name,
        e.country_code
    ));
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var country_list = [{
  "country_code": "AD",
  "country_name": "Andorra"
}, {
  "country_code": "AE",
  "country_name": "United Arab Emirates"
}, {
  "country_code": "AF",
  "country_name": "Afghanistan"
}, {
  "country_code": "AG",
  "country_name": "Antigua and Barbuda"
}, {
  "country_code": "AI",
  "country_name": "Anguilla"
}, {
  "country_code": "AL",
  "country_name": "Albania"
}, {
  "country_code": "AM",
  "country_name": "Armenia"
}, {
  "country_code": "AN",
  "country_name": "Netherlands Antilles"
}, {
  "country_code": "AO",
  "country_name": "Angola"
}, {
  "country_code": "AQ",
  "country_name": "Antarctica"
}, {
  "country_code": "AR",
  "country_name": "Argentina"
}, {
  "country_code": "AS",
  "country_name": "American Samoa"
}, {
  "country_code": "AT",
  "country_name": "Austria"
}/*...and so on...*/];
var selectOptions = document.getElementById("country").options;
country_list.forEach(function(e) {
  selectOptions.add(new Option(
    e.country_name,
    e.country_code
  ));
});
```

```html
<select id="country"></select>
```

Comment: It does not seem to do the trick, i do have the country list in another .js file. in my html file i using script tags to add the dropdown

Comment: @acer: It works provided A) You have a `select` box with the `id` `"country"`, and B) You have `country_list_` as shown.

Comment: @acer: I've added live examples. I had to shorten the country list, SO limits the size of an answer. Also, apologies, I had the argument order of the `Option` constructor reversed (but you would have figured that out).

Comment: Thanks, live example helped and solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are using `opt` which is an `object` not just `String`:

```js
var country_list = [{
  "country_code": "AD",
  "country_name": "Andorra"
}, {
  "country_code": "AE",
  "country_name": "United Arab Emirates"
}, {
  "country_code": "AF",
  "country_name": "Afghanistan"
}, {
  "country_code": "AG",
  "country_name": "Antigua and Barbuda"
}, {
  "country_code": "AI",
  "country_name": "Anguilla"
}, {
  "country_code": "AL",
  "country_name": "Albania"
}, {
  "country_code": "AM",
  "country_name": "Armenia"
}, {
  "country_code": "AN",
  "country_name": "Netherlands Antilles"
}, {
  "country_code": "AO",
  "country_name": "Angola"
}, {
  "country_code": "AQ",
  "country_name": "Antarctica"
}, {
  "country_code": "AR",
  "country_name": "Argentina"
}, {
  "country_code": "AS",
  "country_name": "American Samoa"
}, {
  "country_code": "AT",
  "country_name": "Austria"
}, {
  "country_code": "AU",
  "country_name": "Australia"
}, {
  "country_code": "AW",
  "country_name": "Aruba"
}, {
  "country_code": "AZ",
  "country_name": "Azerbaijan"
}, {
  "country_code": "BA",
  "country_name": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
}, {
  "country_code": "BB",
  "country_name": "Barbados"
}, {
  "country_code": "BD",
  "country_name": "Bangladesh"
}, {
  "country_code": "BE",
  "country_name": "Belgium"
}, {
  "country_code": "BF",
  "country_name": "Burkina Faso"
}, {
  "country_code": "BG",
  "country_name": "Bulgaria"
}, {
  "country_code": "BH",
  "country_name": "Bahrain"
}, {
  "country_code": "BI",
  "country_name": "Burundi"
}, {
  "country_code": "BJ",
  "country_name": "Benin"
}, {
  "country_code": "BM",
  "country_name": "Bermuda"
}, {
  "country_code": "BN",
  "country_name": "Brunei Darussalam"
}, {
  "country_code": "BO",
  "country_name": "Bolivia"
}, {
  "country_code": "BR",
  "country_name": "Brazil"
}, {
  "country_code": "BS",
  "country_name": "Bahamas"
}, {
  "country_code": "BT",
  "country_name": "Bhutan"
}, {
  "country_code": "BV",
  "country_name": "Bouvet Island"
}, {
  "country_code": "BW",
  "country_name": "Botswana"
}, {
  "country_code": "BY",
  "country_name": "Belarus"
}, {
  "country_code": "BZ",
  "country_name": "Belize"
}, {
  "country_code": "CA",
  "country_name": "Canada"
}, {
  "country_code": "CC",
  "country_name": "Cocos (Keeling) Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "CF",
  "country_name": "Central African Republic"
}, {
  "country_code": "CG",
  "country_name": "Congo"
}, {
  "country_code": "CH",
  "country_name": "Switzerland"
}, {
  "country_code": "CI",
  "country_name": "Cote D'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)"
}, {
  "country_code": "CK",
  "country_name": "Cook Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "CL",
  "country_name": "Chile"
}, {
  "country_code": "CM",
  "country_name": "Cameroon"
}, {
  "country_code": "CN",
  "country_name": "China"
}, {
  "country_code": "CO",
  "country_name": "Colombia"
}, {
  "country_code": "CR",
  "country_name": "Costa Rica"
}, {
  "country_code": "CS",
  "country_name": "Czechoslovakia (former)"
}, {
  "country_code": "CU",
  "country_name": "Cuba"
}, {
  "country_code": "CV",
  "country_name": "Cape Verde"
}, {
  "country_code": "CX",
  "country_name": "Christmas Island"
}, {
  "country_code": "CY",
  "country_name": "Cyprus"
}, {
  "country_code": "CZ",
  "country_name": "Czech Republic"
}, {
  "country_code": "DE",
  "country_name": "Germany"
}, {
  "country_code": "DJ",
  "country_name": "Djibouti"
}, {
  "country_code": "DK",
  "country_name": "Denmark"
}, {
  "country_code": "DM",
  "country_name": "Dominica"
}, {
  "country_code": "DO",
  "country_name": "Dominican Republic"
}, {
  "country_code": "DZ",
  "country_name": "Algeria"
}, {
  "country_code": "EC",
  "country_name": "Ecuador"
}, {
  "country_code": "EE",
  "country_name": "Estonia"
}, {
  "country_code": "EG",
  "country_name": "Egypt"
}, {
  "country_code": "EH",
  "country_name": "Western Sahara"
}, {
  "country_code": "ER",
  "country_name": "Eritrea"
}, {
  "country_code": "ES",
  "country_name": "Spain"
}, {
  "country_code": "ET",
  "country_name": "Ethiopia"
}, {
  "country_code": "FI",
  "country_name": "Finland"
}, {
  "country_code": "FJ",
  "country_name": "Fiji"
}, {
  "country_code": "FK",
  "country_name": "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)"
}, {
  "country_code": "FM",
  "country_name": "Micronesia"
}, {
  "country_code": "FO",
  "country_name": "Faroe Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "FR",
  "country_name": "France"
}, {
  "country_code": "FX",
  "country_name": "France, Metropolitan"
}, {
  "country_code": "GA",
  "country_name": "Gabon"
}, {
  "country_code": "GB",
  "country_name": "Great Britain (UK)"
}, {
  "country_code": "GD",
  "country_name": "Grenada"
}, {
  "country_code": "GE",
  "country_name": "Georgia"
}, {
  "country_code": "GF",
  "country_name": "French Guiana"
}, {
  "country_code": "GH",
  "country_name": "Ghana"
}, {
  "country_code": "GI",
  "country_name": "Gibraltar"
}, {
  "country_code": "GL",
  "country_name": "Greenland"
}, {
  "country_code": "GM",
  "country_name": "Gambia"
}, {
  "country_code": "GN",
  "country_name": "Guinea"
}, {
  "country_code": "GP",
  "country_name": "Guadeloupe"
}, {
  "country_code": "GQ",
  "country_name": "Equatorial Guinea"
}, {
  "country_code": "GR",
  "country_name": "Greece"
}, {
  "country_code": "GS",
  "country_name": "S. Georgia and S. Sandwich Isls."
}, {
  "country_code": "GT",
  "country_name": "Guatemala"
}, {
  "country_code": "GU",
  "country_name": "Guam"
}, {
  "country_code": "GW",
  "country_name": "Guinea-Bissau"
}, {
  "country_code": "GY",
  "country_name": "Guyana"
}, {
  "country_code": "HK",
  "country_name": "Hong Kong"
}, {
  "country_code": "HM",
  "country_name": "Heard and McDonald Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "HN",
  "country_name": "Honduras"
}, {
  "country_code": "HR",
  "country_name": "Croatia (Hrvatska)"
}, {
  "country_code": "HT",
  "country_name": "Haiti"
}, {
  "country_code": "HU",
  "country_name": "Hungary"
}, {
  "country_code": "ID",
  "country_name": "Indonesia"
}, {
  "country_code": "IE",
  "country_name": "Ireland"
}, {
  "country_code": "IL",
  "country_name": "Israel"
}, {
  "country_code": "IN",
  "country_name": "India"
}, {
  "country_code": "IO",
  "country_name": "British Indian Ocean Territory"
}, {
  "country_code": "IQ",
  "country_name": "Iraq"
}, {
  "country_code": "IR",
  "country_name": "Iran"
}, {
  "country_code": "IS",
  "country_name": "Iceland"
}, {
  "country_code": "IT",
  "country_name": "Italy"
}, {
  "country_code": "JM",
  "country_name": "Jamaica"
}, {
  "country_code": "JO",
  "country_name": "Jordan"
}, {
  "country_code": "JP",
  "country_name": "Japan"
}, {
  "country_code": "KE",
  "country_name": "Kenya"
}, {
  "country_code": "KG",
  "country_name": "Kyrgyzstan"
}, {
  "country_code": "KH",
  "country_name": "Cambodia"
}, {
  "country_code": "KI",
  "country_name": "Kiribati"
}, {
  "country_code": "KM",
  "country_name": "Comoros"
}, {
  "country_code": "KN",
  "country_name": "Saint Kitts and Nevis"
}, {
  "country_code": "KP",
  "country_name": "Korea (North)"
}, {
  "country_code": "KR",
  "country_name": "Korea (South)"
}, {
  "country_code": "KW",
  "country_name": "Kuwait"
}, {
  "country_code": "KY",
  "country_name": "Cayman Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "KZ",
  "country_name": "Kazakhstan"
}, {
  "country_code": "LA",
  "country_name": "Laos"
}, {
  "country_code": "LB",
  "country_name": "Lebanon"
}, {
  "country_code": "LC",
  "country_name": "Saint Lucia"
}, {
  "country_code": "LI",
  "country_name": "Liechtenstein"
}, {
  "country_code": "LK",
  "country_name": "Sri Lanka"
}, {
  "country_code": "LR",
  "country_name": "Liberia"
}, {
  "country_code": "LS",
  "country_name": "Lesotho"
}, {
  "country_code": "LT",
  "country_name": "Lithuania"
}, {
  "country_code": "LU",
  "country_name": "Luxembourg"
}, {
  "country_code": "LV",
  "country_name": "Latvia"
}, {
  "country_code": "LY",
  "country_name": "Libya"
}, {
  "country_code": "MA",
  "country_name": "Morocco"
}, {
  "country_code": "MC",
  "country_name": "Monaco"
}, {
  "country_code": "MD",
  "country_name": "Moldova"
}, {
  "country_code": "MG",
  "country_name": "Madagascar"
}, {
  "country_code": "MH",
  "country_name": "Marshall Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "MK",
  "country_name": "Macedonia"
}, {
  "country_code": "ML",
  "country_name": "Mali"
}, {
  "country_code": "MM",
  "country_name": "Myanmar"
}, {
  "country_code": "MN",
  "country_name": "Mongolia"
}, {
  "country_code": "MO",
  "country_name": "Macau"
}, {
  "country_code": "MP",
  "country_name": "Northern Mariana Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "MQ",
  "country_name": "Martinique"
}, {
  "country_code": "MR",
  "country_name": "Mauritania"
}, {
  "country_code": "MS",
  "country_name": "Montserrat"
}, {
  "country_code": "MT",
  "country_name": "Malta"
}, {
  "country_code": "MU",
  "country_name": "Mauritius"
}, {
  "country_code": "MV",
  "country_name": "Maldives"
}, {
  "country_code": "MW",
  "country_name": "Malawi"
}, {
  "country_code": "MX",
  "country_name": "Mexico"
}, {
  "country_code": "MY",
  "country_name": "Malaysia"
}, {
  "country_code": "MZ",
  "country_name": "Mozambique"
}, {
  "country_code": "NA",
  "country_name": "Namibia"
}, {
  "country_code": "NC",
  "country_name": "New Caledonia"
}, {
  "country_code": "NE",
  "country_name": "Niger"
}, {
  "country_code": "NF",
  "country_name": "Norfolk Island"
}, {
  "country_code": "NG",
  "country_name": "Nigeria"
}, {
  "country_code": "NI",
  "country_name": "Nicaragua"
}, {
  "country_code": "NL",
  "country_name": "Netherlands"
}, {
  "country_code": "NO",
  "country_name": "Norway"
}, {
  "country_code": "NP",
  "country_name": "Nepal"
}, {
  "country_code": "NR",
  "country_name": "Nauru"
}, {
  "country_code": "NT",
  "country_name": "Neutral Zone"
}, {
  "country_code": "NU",
  "country_name": "Niue"
}, {
  "country_code": "NZ",
  "country_name": "New Zealand (Aotearoa)"
}, {
  "country_code": "OM",
  "country_name": "Oman"
}, {
  "country_code": "PA",
  "country_name": "Panama"
}, {
  "country_code": "PE",
  "country_name": "Peru"
}, {
  "country_code": "PF",
  "country_name": "French Polynesia"
}, {
  "country_code": "PG",
  "country_name": "Papua New Guinea"
}, {
  "country_code": "PH",
  "country_name": "Philippines"
}, {
  "country_code": "PK",
  "country_name": "Pakistan"
}, {
  "country_code": "PL",
  "country_name": "Poland"
}, {
  "country_code": "PM",
  "country_name": "St. Pierre and Miquelon"
}, {
  "country_code": "PN",
  "country_name": "Pitcairn"
}, {
  "country_code": "PR",
  "country_name": "Puerto Rico"
}, {
  "country_code": "PT",
  "country_name": "Portugal"
}, {
  "country_code": "PW",
  "country_name": "Palau"
}, {
  "country_code": "PY",
  "country_name": "Paraguay"
}, {
  "country_code": "QA",
  "country_name": "Qatar"
}, {
  "country_code": "RE",
  "country_name": "Reunion"
}, {
  "country_code": "RO",
  "country_name": "Romania"
}, {
  "country_code": "RU",
  "country_name": "Russia"
}, {
  "country_code": "RW",
  "country_name": "Rwanda"
}, {
  "country_code": "SA",
  "country_name": "Saudi Arabia"
}, {
  "country_code": "Sb",
  "country_name": "Solomon Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "SC",
  "country_name": "Seychelles"
}, {
  "country_code": "SD",
  "country_name": "Sudan"
}, {
  "country_code": "SE",
  "country_name": "Sweden"
}, {
  "country_code": "SG",
  "country_name": "Singapore"
}, {
  "country_code": "SH",
  "country_name": "St. Helena"
}, {
  "country_code": "SI",
  "country_name": "Slovenia"
}, {
  "country_code": "SJ",
  "country_name": "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "SK",
  "country_name": "Slovak Republic"
}, {
  "country_code": "SL",
  "country_name": "Sierra Leone"
}, {
  "country_code": "SM",
  "country_name": "San Marino"
}, {
  "country_code": "SN",
  "country_name": "Senegal"
}, {
  "country_code": "SO",
  "country_name": "Somalia"
}, {
  "country_code": "SR",
  "country_name": "Suriname"
}, {
  "country_code": "ST",
  "country_name": "Sao Tome and Principe"
}, {
  "country_code": "SU",
  "country_name": "USSR (former)"
}, {
  "country_code": "SV",
  "country_name": "El Salvador"
}, {
  "country_code": "SY",
  "country_name": "Syria"
}, {
  "country_code": "SZ",
  "country_name": "Swaziland"
}, {
  "country_code": "TC",
  "country_name": "Turks and Caicos Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "TD",
  "country_name": "Chad"
}, {
  "country_code": "TF",
  "country_name": "French Southern Territories"
}, {
  "country_code": "TG",
  "country_name": "Togo"
}, {
  "country_code": "TH",
  "country_name": "Thailand"
}, {
  "country_code": "TJ",
  "country_name": "Tajikistan"
}, {
  "country_code": "TK",
  "country_name": "Tokelau"
}, {
  "country_code": "TM",
  "country_name": "Turkmenistan"
}, {
  "country_code": "TN",
  "country_name": "Tunisia"
}, {
  "country_code": "TO",
  "country_name": "Tonga"
}, {
  "country_code": "TP",
  "country_name": "East Timor"
}, {
  "country_code": "TR",
  "country_name": "Turkey"
}, {
  "country_code": "TT",
  "country_name": "Trinidad and Tobago"
}, {
  "country_code": "TV",
  "country_name": "Tuvalu"
}, {
  "country_code": "TW",
  "country_name": "Taiwan"
}, {
  "country_code": "TZ",
  "country_name": "Tanzania"
}, {
  "country_code": "UA",
  "country_name": "Ukraine"
}, {
  "country_code": "UG",
  "country_name": "Uganda"
}, {
  "country_code": "UK",
  "country_name": "United Kingdom"
}, {
  "country_code": "UM",
  "country_name": "US Minor Outlying Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "US",
  "country_name": "United States"
}, {
  "country_code": "UY",
  "country_name": "Uruguay"
}, {
  "country_code": "UZ",
  "country_name": "Uzbekistan"
}, {
  "country_code": "VA",
  "country_name": "Vatican City State (Holy See)"
}, {
  "country_code": "VC",
  "country_name": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"
}, {
  "country_code": "VE",
  "country_name": "Venezuela"
}, {
  "country_code": "VG",
  "country_name": "Virgin Islands (British)"
}, {
  "country_code": "VI",
  "country_name": "Virgin Islands (U.S.)"
}, {
  "country_code": "VN",
  "country_name": "Viet Nam"
}, {
  "country_code": "VU",
  "country_name": "Vanuatu"
}, {
  "country_code": "WF",
  "country_name": "Wallis and Futuna Islands"
}, {
  "country_code": "WS",
  "country_name": "Samoa"
}, {
  "country_code": "YE",
  "country_name": "Yemen"
}, {
  "country_code": "YT",
  "country_name": "Mayotte"
}, {
  "country_code": "YU",
  "country_name": "Yugoslavia"
}, {
  "country_code": "ZA",
  "country_name": "South Africa"
}, {
  "country_code": "ZM",
  "country_name": "Zambia"
}, {
  "country_code": "ZR",
  "country_name": "Zaire"
}, {
  "country_code": "ZW",
  "country_name": "Zimbabwe"
}];

var dd = document.getElementById("country").options;
var c;
for (var i = 0; country_list.length > i; i++) {
  c = country_list[i];
  dd.add(new Option(c.country_name, c.country_code, c.country_code === "US"))
}
```

```html
<select id="country"></select>
```

Here, I am using the `Option` to add items to the country list, constructor takes three args, `Option(<text>, <value>, <selected>)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this just add things from your JSON (country_name,country_code)

```
var select = document.getElementById("country");
var el = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < country_list.length; i++) {
   el = document.createElement("option");
   el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(country_list[i].country_name));
   el.value = country_list[i].country_code;
   select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: Please comment when you vote down was the soln not working, was it not following standards ??

Comment: Commenting downvotes is specifically *not* recommended. Your earlier version was using `textContent`, which doesn't work well cross-browser, which may have been an issue. The answer also adds nothing relative to the existing answer.